# Spring XD: how to handle messages being processed while undeploying a stream

Tags: spring-xd

Is there any possible customizations to requeue messages being processed while a stream undeploy operation is occuring?

Let's say I have 10 unacked messages in RabbitMQ being processed by a slow processor during an undeploy, how can I ensure those messages are not going to be delivered to the DLQ because of "dispatcher has no subscribers" but instead being re-queued in the input processor queue?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't get such exceptions; modules are stopped left to right, so the inbound channel adapter should be stopped before the downstream components are unsubscribed from their input channels.

Is this a custom module?

Comment: The stream is composed of a RabbitMQ source, two custom processors and a custom Elasticsearch sink. The processors are always defining a filter and a transformation (input -> filter -> transformation -> output).

Comment: Hmmm - when a module is undeployed, the message bus is called to shut down the inbound channel adapter that feeds the input channel before the module itself is stopped (unsubscribing from the channels). The listener container will wait up to 5 seconds for tasks to complete before giving up; so this might be problem is if your module(s) can take more than 5 seconds for a message. While this 5 seconds is configurable, the bus currently does not expose a property to set it. If you turn on DEBUG logging for all of `org.springframework` during an undeploy you should see bean lifecycle messages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just had some time to investigate further. If I'm right, the idea would be to customize the shutdownTimeout property of the org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer class. It was solving my issue by setting the value from a debug session. Is there any plans to allow configuring this timeout from the Spring XD configuration?